# Stimulsoft report viewer JS disable controls on toolbar ( not hide buttons )

Tags: stimulsoft

I want to disable all the controls on the Stimulsoft report toolbar. in the documentation, I have found options like

```
var options = new Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewerOptions();
options.toolbar.visible = false; // to hide toolbar
options.toolbar.showOpenButton = false; // to hide open button
var viewer = new Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(options, 'StiViewer', false);
viewer.report = report;
viewer.renderHtml('viewer');
```

But I don't want this behavior of toolbar or its specific controls being hidden, I just want controls to be disabled and visible.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any solution for it in the documentation of stimulsoft. so I just gave it a fix by disabling the pointer-events using CSS.

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".stiJsViewerToolBarTable td"), (element) => {
                const smlButton = element.querySelector('div')
                if (smlButton) smlButton.style = "margin-right:3px; margin-left:1px;";
                element.style = "opacity: 0.8; pointer-events: none; cursor: not-allowed !important;"
            })
```